# dict to pandas dataframe - orient by?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that I am trying to read / store as `pandas` dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

j = {
     'fields': [
                {'type': 'text', 'id': 'Status'},
                {'type': 'text', 'id': 'gx_location'},
                {'type': 'text', 'id': 'ASSESSORS_PARCEL_NUMBER'},
                {'type': 'text', 'id': 'APPLICANT'}
               ],
     'records': [['Active',
                  '     ,   ',
                  '0',
                  '1759764'],
                 ['Active',
                  '     ,   ',
                  '0',
                  '1759264'],
                 ['Active',
                  '0  CHERRY AV  , SAN JOSE CA 95125-0000',
                  '0',
                  '1759264']]
   }

pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j, orient="index")
```

When I run the above line, I get 2 rows with index `fields` and `records`. The off the shelf `orient` options don't work; because I'd like get `id` from `fields` to be column labels and data from `records` key.

```
Status      gx_location ASSESSORS_PARCEL_NUMBER APPLICANT
Active             ,                          0   1759764
Active             ,                          0   1759264
Active  0  CHERRY AV...                       0   1759264
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pandas convenience shortcuts are nice, but when your need doesn't fit their very narrow parameters, throw them away and just get the job done.  Fortunately, what you need is very easy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(j['records'], columns=[k['id'] for k in j['fields']])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Status                             gx_location ASSESSORS_PARCEL_NUMBER APPLICANT
0  Active                                    ,                          0   1759764
1  Active                                    ,                          0   1759264
2  Active  0  CHERRY AV  , SAN JOSE CA 95125-0000                       0   1759264
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's appropriate for you to adjust the spacing in an answer.  That's strictly a matter of personal preference.  You can't say you "improved" the coding style.  It's just different.

Comment: I'm following [what PEP 8 says](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#pet-peeves): *"Avoid extraneous whitespace ... Immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces"*. Plus the spacing inside the list was inconsistent anyway, with one at the end but none at the start. But, it's not super important for me; I just wanted to improve the readability by applying the standard style, and only cause I was already editing. BTW, I didn't get a notification for your comment; I just happened to be back here. You can @-tag editors to alert them.